# Resize viewBox when dragging a node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, force-layout

I created force layout graph, based on d3.v2 library, in my project.
It works well in almost of it part, but there are one thing that I want to change.  So when I draged node out of graph's block after that I can't reach it. For solve that problem I added viewBox attribute for my graph and change little "tick" event, so now it looks like

```
force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        if (d.fixed != true) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        } else {
            return "translate(" + d.px + "," + d.py + ")";
        }

        // here is what I tried to do
        if (d.x < 960 && d.y < 600) {
            vis.attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 600");
        } else if (d.x > 960 && d.y < 600) {
            vis.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + d.x + " 600");
        } else if (d.x < 960 && d.y > 600) {
            vis.attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 " + d.y);
        } else {
            vis.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + d.x + " " + d.y)
        }
    });
});
```

But viewBox changes only when I drag node, which according to last element in nodes array.
So I want to know is there any way to change viewBox size when drag any node.
Thank for any answer or advice!

Comment: Can you share a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example?

Comment: @Terry I created jsfiddle to show little example. I remove most logic and left only for this example works. In this example when you drag out C node viewBox will change, but on drag other node nothing happens. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/IMykytiv/6rx3Lxfu/2/)

Comment: Just a curiosity: any reason for using v2, a version released 7 years ago? This is 2018 and v5 is about to be released!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why only the **last** node is capable of changing the `viewBox` is quite simple. Let's examine your code.

All your `if...else` statements are inside the callback for the `attr` of the `node` selection:

```
node.attr("transform", function (d) {
```

Because of that, the datum (`d`) will be evaluated for **each** node in the selection. So, if you drag the node `B` to the border of the chart, even if its value is greater than `300`, the value of the node `C` (less than `300`), when evaluated, will override it and set the viewBox back to `"0 0 300 200"`.

**Solution**:

Let's calculate the *maximum* value for each node:

```
  var maxX = d3.max(node.data().map(d => d.x));
  var maxY = d3.max(node.data().map(d => d.y));
```

Then, you can use your `if...else` statements (which can be improved, by the way) dealing with `maxX` and `maxY`.

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fc5myafx/